# Let $R$ be a ring with a unique element $e\neq 0$ such that $ex=x$ for all $x\in R.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with a unique element $e\neq 0$ such that $ex=x$ for all $x\in R.$ Prove that $e$ is an identity element of $R.$ Does the above result hold if $e$ is not a unique element? Justify.

We are given that, $ex=x$ for all $x\in R.$ We need to prove that, if  $e\neq 0$ is unique then, $xe=x,\forall x\in R.$

So, first of all I took an $x\in R$.

Then I noted that, $ex=x\implies xex=x^2$ and $exe=xe$.

Also, it is true that $(xe)^2=x^2e$ and $(ex)^2=x^2.$ Thus, we have, $(xe)^2=(ex)^2e.$

My aim was to show that $xe=x$.

Judging from the second question, I thought that the point $e$ is unique should be used somewhere. My idea was tgen to find a "new" $e'$ that serves as a left identity. Then for that, I could have said, $e'=e$ and then, maybe it might have been easier to verify, that $xe'=xe=x.$

But till now, I have not been able to make any significant progress with this problem.

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a \in R$.
Note that, for each $x \in R$,
$$
(ae-a+e)x = aex-ax+ex = x.
$$
Hence, $ae-a+e=e$ by uniqueness, and then $ae=a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if $e$ was not unique. Would then $e$ still be an identity? I think it's not. But then I have to justify this with the help of a counter example, isn't it? Unfortunately, I can't find any.

Comment: @ThomasFinley You're welcome! No, uniqueness is necessary. Have you seen Kenta's answer?

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb Z&\mathbb Z\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$e=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $e$ is a left unit but not a right unit.

Note that $e$ is not unique, since
$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is also a left unit.